# Line integral with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A curve C in polar form $r=f(\theta)$ is parameterized by $C(\theta) = \langle f(\theta)\cos(\theta),f(\theta) \sin(\theta)\rangle$ because the x- and y-coordinates are given by $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r \sin(\theta)$.  Evaluate $\int_C(x-y)^2ds$ where C is given by $r= 2 \cos(\theta)$ ,    $0\le \theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I'm not sure I'm understanding this question. If $r= 2 cos(\theta)$, then  $C(\theta) = \langle2\cos^2(\theta),2\cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)\rangle$

Since $C'(\theta) = \langle -4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta), 2\cos(2\theta)\rangle$, $||C'(\theta)|| = 2$. The integral is set up like this:
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\cos^2(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2d\theta$$

This is not an easy integral to do, unless I am missing something. Any tips?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about how you wrote down the problem, however I'm pretty sure that $||C'(\theta)|| \neq 2$ according to your $C'$.

Comment: The derivative of $2\cos^2(\theta)$ is not $-4\sin(\theta)$. It is $-4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Damn you're right. Sorry I had a brain fart... !

Comment: Don't worry about it! No problem

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(2\cos^2\theta-\sin2\theta)^2d\theta$$
$$I=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4\theta d\theta+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^22\theta\,d\theta-8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^3\theta\sin\theta \,d\theta$$
use 
$$\sin^22\theta=\frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2x-1}\theta\cos^{2y-1}\theta\,d\theta=\frac12\beta(x,y)$$
Indeed
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^4\theta d\theta=\frac12\beta(\frac 12,\frac 52)$$
and
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^3\theta\sin\theta \,d\theta=\frac12\beta( 1,2)$$

**Other way**
$$\cos^3\theta \sin\theta=(1-\sin^2\theta) \cos\theta \sin \theta$$
set $u=\sin\theta$
and

$$\cos^4\theta=\frac{1}{4}(1+2\cos2\theta)+\frac{1}{8}(1+\cos4\theta)$$

Comment: Made an edit to the problem, the limits for $\theta$ are 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Sorry about that!

Comment: It was edited...

Comment: I don't understand what you did there. Where do the last three equations come from? What does the β mean? I haven't learned that...

Comment: $\beta(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$

Comment: I haven't learned any of this. What does that mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Is there a way to do this problem without using those gamma functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42473/discussion-between-dubbler26-and-behrouz-maleki).